# Localisation in one single .string file (XCODE)

Tags: ios, xcode

I have several `.storyboard` and `.xib` files. The `xcode` localisation feature created a separate .string file for each one.

How do I combine all language `.string` files into one file (that i can use in the entire application), so that I get a better overview of my texts.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way.

The only way that I can think of is remove **all** the texts from **all** the UI Elements from **all** .storyboard and .xib and then set all the texts in **code**.

Then only you can only use one .string file for each language.